# Convergence of $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^m)/x^n dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (x^m)}{x^n}dx $$

Putting $x^m = t$

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{m}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t^{(\frac{m+n-1}{m})}}dt
\end{align}
$$

By applying Dirichlet Test I've been able to prove that the integrand is convergent when $1-m < n$.

But the answer given is $1-m < n < m+1$. Can you give me any hint on how to get the second condition?

Comment: Were the limits in the actual problem from $0$ to $\infty$ (not $1$ to $\infty$)?

Comment: If $m>0$, then we must have $n>1-m$ for convergence.

Comment: @Mark Viola That I've been able to show. How to prove $n<m+1$ ?

Comment: $n<m+1$ cannot possibly be true. If it converges for $n$ given $m$, then it converges for $n+1, n+2,...$ etc.

Comment: There was a mistake in the question the bounds of integration are from $0$ to $\infty$. Sorry, it was a typo by the TA. I'm able to solve the problem and will post the solution also. Thanks for your support.